# pandas.DataFrame slicing accoring to another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

How can I create df3 according to df1 and df2?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[10,20,30],[100,200,300]], index=['a','b','c'],columns=['A','B','C'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['A','C'],['B','A'],['C','B']],index=['a','b','c'],columns=[0,1])
df3 = pd.DataFrame([[1,3],[20,10],[300,200]], index=['a','b','c'],columns=[0,1])
```

Here is my code,

```
df1.apply(lambda x: x.loc[df2.loc[x.name,:]], axis=1)
```

This is df1

[image: df1]

This is df2

[image: df2]

This is df3

[image]

Comment: Please post your dataframes as text so potential answerers could copy and paste them: [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: What do you mean by "create df3 according to df1 and df2"? Please clarify.

Comment: I mean slicing df1 by df2. My poor English...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you can do with `lookup` after `stack` with df2

```
s=df2.stack()
s
Out[321]: 
a  0    A
   1    C
b  0    B
   1    A
c  0    C
   1    B
dtype: object
pd.Series(df1.lookup(s.index.get_level_values(0),s),index=s.index).unstack()
Out[322]: 
     0    1
a    1    3
b   20   10
c  300  200
```

Or with `apply`

```
df2.apply(lambda x : df1.loc[x.name,x].values,axis=1)
Out[327]: 
     0    1
a    1    3
b   20   10
c  300  200
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

use `lookup`

```
In [993]: pd.DataFrame({k: df1.lookup(df2.index, df2[c]) for k, c in enumerate(df2)},
                       index=df1.index)
Out[993]:
     0    1
a    1    3
b   20   10
c  300  200
```

Or

```
In [973]: df2.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(df1.loc[x.name, y] for y in x), axis=1)
Out[973]:
     0    1
a    1    3
b   20   10
c  300  200
```